# Canvas won't update?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making an online checkers game.

I added piece moving capabilities and the pieces move, but they don't appear to move.

Here is a JSFiddle I made of my project: https://jsfiddle.net/y1s0uoq6/

When you click on a piece and then click on one of the options to move, the pieces x y coordinates update and they can be clicked at the new spot, but the checker does not appear at the new spot.

I update all of the checkers' positions with this:

```
for(var checker of this.checkers) {
    checker.draw();         
}
```

Yet the checkers still don't update graphically. Only their position seems to update.

Why is this?
Can someone shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line within the `.draw()` function:

```
ctx.ellipse(x+32,y+32,28,28,45 * Math.PI/180,0,2 * Math.PI);
```

You are using `x` and `y`, which are the *original* coordinates used when the checker is created - they're the arguments from your `Checker()` constructor. You need to use `this.x` and `this.y` to get the *current* coordinates:

```
ctx.ellipse(this.x+32,this.y+32,28,28,45 * Math.PI/180,0,2 * Math.PI);
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y1s0uoq6/1/